# Why does one use different materials for cathode and anode in the photoelectric effect experiment

Tags: experimental-physics, education, photoelectric-effect, experimental-technique

All photoeletric lab experiments I have seen so far have a setup where you have different materials for cathode and anode.

However this raises some experimental difficulties since you have to take the contact EMF into account.

From a pedagogic point of view it seems to be better to use just the same material for anode and cathode.

What are the problems in using the same materials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one would use the same metal, then both electrodes would be equally photosensitive, which is not a good idea. Ideally one does not want the anode to produce any electrons, at all, so one would chose a metal with a high work function (in the UV region). As far as teaching is concerned, there is nothing wrong with teaching students that science is (almost) always about "playing with handicap". Nature rarely ever presents us with kitchen clean effects and we have to use our minds to separate what we are interested in from the interference. I would use this as an opportunity.